# Is there any way in flutter where I can communicate to the devices connected to my local network

Tags: flutter, shelf-router

I am trying to communicate and send data between peers using shelf_router, I was able to do it between two devices using their IPs, but was not able to communicate between multiple devices.

Please can anyone help me with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.